# Page flip script with pinch-zooming

Tags: html, zooming, libraries, page-flipping

There are many scripts out there to cover the pageflip functionality. Actually, pageflip.hu does pretty much all you need and it's also in HTML5..

However, it does not seem to allow zooming in and out which is a shame.

Now, does anyone know of something similar that also let's you zoom in/out. Ideally through pinch gesture?

Comment: I'd avoid linking to things in such a promotional manner as it can be considered as spam by some.

Comment: I have no relation with the link I posted. I'm actually making a point of the script not being what I need and stating I'm looking for something better.

Comment: ozke: Sorry, I accidentally missed that line during the edit. The post should be good now.